# TYPO3 RealURL does not generate link in workspace

Tags: typo3, realurl

Does anybody know, if TYPO3 extension RealURL has support fo workspace?

If I switch to workspace and click to preview each of links on page has href="mydomain.com/index.php?id=xxx" instead of href="mydomain.com/page-1".

In LIVE version everythings OK

I have used automatic conf of RealURL and I have multidomain page...

Answer (score 2):

The Workspace Preview may look like the Frontend, but in fact it runs in Backend context. The Backend may run on a different port, with a different URL etc. and therefore you don't have speaking URLs available in this context. So there is no solution, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know, if TYPO3 extension RealURL has support fo workspace?

No, RealURL does not do anything when working in a workspace. This is by design.